# Is the MongoDB $push operator the way to add an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, spring-3, mongodb-java

I'm using MongoDB and Spring 3. I have the following domain object:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<Post> posts;
}
```

I want to add a `Post` to a `User`, but what is the best/most efficient way to do that? I can see a way to do this programmatically - find the user, add a new post object to the list and save the user again - but I don't think this is very elegant or efficient.

From the documentation it seems like I need to use the `$push` operator but I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this with Spring's MongoTemplate. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$push would be the correct way to add a new document to the array.

You can see example code in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/chris.e.richardson/mongodb-for-java-developers-with-spring-data) (slide 22).  The relevant line would be:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(collection, 
... new Query(where("_id").is(...)),
... new Update().push("field", dbo));
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I used the following: `mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is("username_1")), new Update().push("posts", newPostObject), User.class);` I think I got a bit confused because I was trying to user the `Update` class statically - like i've seen done in many examples - and this did not allow the `push` method.